Get the name of a decorated class given the class object
I have decorator function and a simple class that's decorated:
import typing


def mydeco(cls: type) -> typing.Callable:
    def inner(*args: typing.Any, **kwargs: typing.Any) -> object:
        return cls(*args, **kwargs)

    return inner


@mydeco
class Wheels:
    def __init__(self, count: int) -> None:
        self.count = count


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Wheels)                         # <function mydeco.<locals>.inner at 0x7f8d663b6d40>
    print(Wheels.__class__)               # <class 'function'>
    print(Wheels.__qualname__)            # mydeco.<locals>.inner
    print(Wheels.__class__.__name__)      # function
    print(Wheels.__class__.__qualname__)  # function
    print(type(Wheels))                   # <class 'function'>

What I would like is to retrieve something like this <class '__main__.Wheels'>, or at least just the name of the class Wheels.

Why did you decorate your class this way in the first place? The right approach here is almost certainly going to be to change your decorator.

You can create an instance of Wheels and then be able to call out the the class name Wheels using the __init__.

@Data_Is_Everything I would like to get the name of Wheels without creating an instance of it, do you know if that is possible?

@user2357112 Let x be an answer that satisfies me trying to retrieve the name of Wheels while it is decorated by mydeco. Do you know of any way to get the name of the class Wheels without instantiating it?

@wordhydrogen: Technically, if you're allowed to hardcode information about inner (particularly the fact that it uses exactly one closure variable, which holds the decorated class), you could inspect __closure__. That's very fragile, though, and if you're hardcoding that kind of information, you might as well just hardcode the 'Wheels' name and print('Wheels').

The information I was looking for was saved a bit deeper inside the Wheels object:
print(Wheels.__closure__[0].cell_contents)  # <class '__main__.Wheels'>

Which is exactly what I needed
